# Task Scheduler missing daily tasks for just 2 days. Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have configured Windows 7 task scheduler to run a daily task at 12:01 AM. It has to start our reporting program that maintains the internal log of its own. It's been working really good since March of this year (for 3 months so far) until May 31 and then June 1st when the task didn't trigger at all. So in the log I have an entry on May 30th and then the next entry is on June 2nd. The question is why it missed those two days???

I exported the task and here it is below.

Also just to let you know, this PC is never turned off or put to sleep. It's our office computer that always stay on. The updates are set up to download and wait. So there's nothing that should've rebooted or tampered with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Author>ReportGenerator Autotask</Author>
    <Description></Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger id="Trigger_ReportGenerator Daily Task. 'c.-program files (x86)-borland-common files-bde-reportgenerator.exe'">
      <StartBoundary>2015-04-30T00:01:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>BTR-PC\Manager</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Common Files\BDE\ReportGenerator.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>-daily -email="name1@domain.net; name2@domain.com"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task has the following options set (which also is the default):

*If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:* **Do not start a new instance**
*Stop the task if it runs longer than*: **Yes, 3 days**

This means that if your task doesn't exit properly then it will continue to run and block new start for 72 hours. Which means the task will not run the next day and not the second day either. But on the third day the non-exited task will be stopped just at the moment before the task starts and so the task can finally start.

Why your task didn't exit properly this one time I can not answer. But I have a task (which starts Powershell and makes a web request)  that was setup just like yours and it just skipped 2 days and apparently it skipped 2 days in September 2021 as well. I guess computers mess up sometimes.